# Java heap usage and session objects on wildfly

Tags: java, session, memory, jax-rs, heap-memory

We have an application in a production environment with about 200 concurrent users. Each user maintains some simple session objects but there are some that have many entries since they reference a users relationship with other users. That means that each user may have a `Map<Integer, Integer>` with 800 entries (total number of users). Is it possible that after some point Java doesn't have enough memory to put this map to the user's session? We don't get any relative exceptions but there is one special case of a resource invocation (where this map is created and persisted) that fails for some users while it works for others. Looking at the stack trace it seems that the `jersey resource function` never gets called. Instead it goes straight to the exception mapper where it fails again and throws another `RuntimeException` which is apparently an `ArrayIndexOutOfBounds` on one of jax-rs's Response functions (`mapException` to be precise). We have no idea why this happens we're just guessing here.

We don't have any tools for profiling at the moment and we don't really have the time to implement them right now. Any insight would be appreciated.

Comment: Depends on your memory setting but even if all 200 users would have a map of 800 Integer - Integer entries (that is 200 maps and 320000 integers) that should only use about 1 to 1.5 MB of heap memory.